# opening and closing of com ports using LabVIEW

Tags: serial-port, labview, visa

I am using LabVIEW to open a com port and get some data. afterwards, I close the interface. but when I want to begin the process again, there is an error being generated. I feel I have to close the port completely before i open it again, but how to do so?

Comment: IMHO LabVIEW is a high order degree PITA when it comes to serial port access. Whoever came up with VISA and its configuration may as well work as torturer. That being said: I implemented my very own serial port access library (as DLL) that's interfaced by VIs doing the proper InterfaceNode calls.

Comment: If you would like help with 'an error being generated', it's useful if you can give details of the error such as the text of the error message or the numeric error code. I've done lots of serial interfacing in LabVIEW and never found a problem with using VISA so the chances are there is a simple solution to the error.

Comment: well i am using a third-party software to receive data. if u must know, it is a USB interface 9205 by Burster company (GERMAN). the error number is -131, also generated by the third party which hasnt given a description for the rror. so i must find out a way out on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the question: you just have to close the VISA session at the end. The reason is that when you open it a second time, it is still openned by the first try which results in an error (the one you see).